# How to replicate a column in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor with shape (k,1) and I want to replicate the first column n times. That is, the resulting tensor should have the shape (k,n) with matrix values copied from the first column. How to achieve this using tf.tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.tile()` operation. For example:

```
a = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3]], dtype = tf.float32)
c = tf.tile(a, [1,3])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
```

returns:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3.]]
```